# PlantUML Class Diagram - field/method visibility in legend

Tags: plantuml

Is it possible to have a key to the class diagram's field/method visibility labels in the legend, using the real icons?

i.e. getting the real icons in the table following diagram

```
@startuml
class Dummy {
-field1
#field2
~method1()
+method2()
}

legend
|= field |= method |=  |
|  -     |   -     | private |
|  #     |   #     | protected |
|  ~     |   ~     | package private |
|  +     |   +     | public |

endlegend
@enduml
```

[image: Example Diagram]

Things I've tried without success:

- Looking for suitable openiconic icons (there don't seem to be any)
- Linking to an image based on the file names on http://plantuml.com/class-diagram (don't exist)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is pretty good (certainly good enough for my purposes):

```
@startuml
class Dummy {
-field1
#field2
~method1()
+method2()
}

skinparam legendBackgroundColor #ffffff
legend

|= field |= method |=  |
|  <img:http://s.plantuml.com/private-field.png>     |   <img:http://s.plantuml.com/private-method.png>     | private |
|  <img:http://s.plantuml.com/protected-field.png>   |   <img:http://s.plantuml.com/protected-method.png>   | protected |
|  <img:http://s.plantuml.com/package-private-field.png>     |   <img:http://s.plantuml.com/package-private-method.png>    | package private |
|  <img:http://s.plantuml.com/public-field.png>     |   <img:http://s.plantuml.com/public-method.png>     | public |

endlegend
@enduml
```

[image: Legend with icons]